# Using Steamworks.NET without being published on Steam (Spacewar)

Tags: steam, piracy, steamworks-api

I've been doing some testing with Steamworks.NET, using the default game id that it provides (480 - Spacewar), and everything seems to work - I can access friends list, use p2p with NAT punch-through, etc, Steam just shows me and my friend playing spacewar, when we are actually playing my basic unity project.

So one thing is not clear to me: if I decided to build a complete p2p-multiplayer game prototype using Steamworks with default game id (easy to implement, easy to test with anyone, seems convinient), would it be safe to launch and give to others, or is there a risk of getting people banned or smth?

I know that spacewar was (or still is) abused in piracy to let people play pirated games online, heard about it being involved in some VAC bans too.

Obviosly I would do that just for testing purposes (if I ended up actually finishing something decent, I would try to just release it on Steam anyway), but I can sort of imagine how someone could abuse this, so I'm just not sure.